# Finding similar products by attributes

Tags: algorithm

I've heard about K nearest neighbor to find a category that an item belongs to but I was wondering if there was an algorithm that will return a list of items based on attributes.

For example given a movie

```
[director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Dec 1776"]
```

The results will return

```
[director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Jan 1996"]
```

instead of

```
[director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Poop Jenkins", release-date: "Sept 1822"]
```

Because the former result matches more attributes "Hill Thompson" and "Will Smith" whereas the former only has one match - Hill Thompson.

Would Cosine Similarity be a good method to solve this problem?

Comment: How to define similarity? Simply by the # of matched key-values? How about a tie?  Is `[director: "Klay Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Dec 1776"]` considered better than your former result (Both has two matches)?

Comment: Oh good question, I guess in that case if we get the same number of attributes then we'll return both

Comment: So there won't be weight / priority among keys? (For eg, if tie, matching director weight higher than matching release-date) Also that means the similarity of the value does not matter? (For eg, if tie in number of matches, director: HiLL Thompson means as bad as director: idcwtfisthis)?

Comment: mmm okay so I guess for weight we can use Tf-Idf, but in my case I was thinking of just returning results with most attribute matches. So all attributes have equal weights. director_weight == release-date_weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Would Cosine Similarity be a good method to solve this problem?*

Yes. It will be good, but with TF-IDF

The most used similarity measures are `Jaccard Similarity` and `Cosine similarity`.
In the scenario given, you can directly use `Jaccard Similarity` and obtain the results you want.

Say,

```
A = {director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Dec 1776"}
B = {director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Jan 1996"}
C = {director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Poop Jenkins", release-date: "Sept 1822"}
D = {director: "Foo Bar", starring-actor: "Poop Jenkins", release-date: "Some date"}
```

The `Jaccard Similarity` will be :

```
J(A,B) = 2 / 4 = 0.5
J(A,C) = 1 / 5 = 0.2
J(C,D) = 1 / 5 = 0.2
```

And as `J(A,B) > J(A,C)` the `K nearest neighbour` method will pick `B` first and then `C`.
In such cases, the `Jaccard similarity` captures the intuition well.

To demonstrate how `Cosine Similarity` is better, add one more attribute :

```
A = {place filmed : "A", director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Dec 1776"}
B = {place filmed : "A", director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Will Smith", release-date: "Jan 1996"}
C = {place filmed : "A", director: "Hill Thompson", starring-actor: "Poop Jenkins", release-date: "Sept 1822"}
D = {place filmed : "A", director: "Foo Bar", starring-actor: "Poop Jenkins", release-date: "Some date"}


J(A,B) = 3 / 5 = 0.6
J(A,C) = 2 / 6 = 0.33
J(C,D) = 2 / 6 = 0.33
```

Notice that the `J(C,A) = J(C,D)`

Which is **wrong** intuition.

Why? 
Because place A seems to be common place for recording movies. Just because two movies are recorded at the same place, we can not conclude that they are similar. So ideally it should be `Sim(C,D) > Sim(C,A)`. Such are the cases where `Jaccard Similarity` fails to capture the intuition and where `Cosine similarity` with `TF-IDF` outperforms.

The problem with `Cosine Similarity` in such cases is the implementation. `Cosine similarity` is defined on vectors. When the data is not numeric, it is hard to create a vector.

One way to create a vector is vector of `boolean`.

For example,
The vector would be formed as :

```
vector = [A,HillThompson,FooBar,WillSmith,Poop Jenkins,Dec 1776,Jan 1996, Sept 1822, Some date]
```

The vectors would be :

```
A = {1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0}
C = {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0}
D = {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1}

J(C,A) = 5 / 12
J(C,D) = 5 / 12
```

Note that the `Jaccard Similarity` still captures wrong intuition. And so would `Cosine Similarity` if TF-IDF is not done.

Now calculate TF-IDF :

```
IDF(A)              = log( 1 + 4 / 4) = 0.30

IDF(HillThompson)   = log( 1 + 4 / 3) = 0.37
IDF(FooBar)         = log( 1 + 4 / 1) = 0.70

IDF(WillSmith)      = log( 1 + 4 / 2) = 0.48
IDF(Poop Jenkins)   = log( 1 + 4 / 2) = 0.48

IDF(Dec 1776)       = log( 1 + 4 / 1) = 0.70
IDF(Jan 1996)       = log( 1 + 4 / 1) = 0.70
IDF(Sept 1822)      = log( 1 + 4 / 1) = 0.70
IDF(Some date)      = log( 1 + 4 / 1) = 0.70
```

IF-IDF vectors would now be :

```
A = {0.30/4, 0.37/4, 0,      0.48/4, 0,       0.70/4, 0, 0,      0}
C = {0.30/4, 0.37/4, 0,      0,      0.48/4,  0,      0, 0.70/4, 0}
D = {0.30/4,      0, 0.70/4, 0,      0.48/4,  0,      0, 0,      0.70/4}

A = {0.075,  0.0925, 0,      0.12,   0,       0.175,  0, 0,     0 } 
C = {0.075,  0.0925, 0,      0,      0.12,    0,      0, 0.175, 0 }
D = {0.075,  0,      0.175,  0,      0.12,    0,      0, 0,     0.175 }

|A| = 0.2433
|C| = 0.2433
|D| = 0.2850
```

Calculate the cosine similarity :

```
Cosine(A,C) = 0.01418 / ( 0.2433 * 0.2433 ) = 0.2395
Cosine(C,D) = 0.0200  / ( 0.2492 * 0.2850 ) = 0.2816
```

Thus, the `Cosine similarity` with `TF-IDF` captures the intuition that `D` is more similar to `C` than `A` is to `C`. And thus it is better than `Jaccard similarity`

**PLEASE NOTE** that I have shown calculations becuase I have done them on PC and not on scientific calculator. There might be chances of errors. Just in case you find one, please rectify it.